# Class to move a sprite in Unity

Tags: c#, beginner, comparative-review, unity3d

I first got introduced to coding with Ruby and now I am learning how to create games in C# with Unity.

I am following a tutorial and I refactored the code to make it easier for me to grasp. I am really curious to know the opinion of more advanced programmers on the following code.

Here is the initial code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CharacterMovement : MonoBehaviour{
  private Rigidbody2D playerRigidBody2D;

  private float movePlayerHorizontal;
  private float movePlayerVertical;
  private Vector2 movement;

  public float speed = 4.0f;

  private Animator playerAnim;

  private SpriteRenderer playerSpriteImage;

  void Awake(){
    playerRigidBody2D = (Rigidbody2D)GetComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D));
    playerAnim=(Animator)GetComponent(typeof(Animator));
    playerSpriteImage=(SpriteRenderer)GetComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer));
  }

  void Update () {
    movePlayerHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    movePlayerVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    movement=new Vector2(movePlayerHorizontal,movePlayerVertical);

    playerRigidBody2D.velocity=movement*speed;

    if(movePlayerVertical==0 && movePlayerHorizontal==0){
      playerAnim.SetBool("moving",false);
    }else{
      playerAnim.SetBool("moving",true);
    }

    if(movePlayerVertical!=0){
      playerAnim.SetBool("xMove",false);
      playerSpriteImage.flipX=false;

      if(movePlayerVertical>0){
        playerAnim.SetInteger("yMove",1);

      }else if(movePlayerVertical<0){
        playerAnim.SetInteger("yMove",-1);

      }
    }else {
      playerAnim.SetInteger("yMove",0);

      if(movePlayerHorizontal>0){
        playerAnim.SetBool("xMove",true);
        playerSpriteImage.flipX=false;

      }else if(movePlayerHorizontal<0){
        playerAnim.SetBool("xMove",true);
        playerSpriteImage.flipX=true;

      }else{
        playerAnim.SetBool("xMove",false);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All the logic is placed inside of the `#Update` method, and there are no private methods to help self-document/declutter it.

This is how I refactored the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterMovement : MonoBehaviour {
  private Rigidbody2D _playerRigidbody2D;
  private Animator _playerAnimator;
  private SpriteRenderer _playerSpriteRenderer;

  private float movePlayerHorizontal;
  private float movePlayerVertical;
  private Vector2 movement;

  public float speed = 4.0f;

  void Awake() {
    _playerRigidbody2D    =    (Rigidbody2D)GetComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D));
    _playerAnimator       =       (Animator)GetComponent(typeof(Animator));
    _playerSpriteRenderer = (SpriteRenderer)GetComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer));
  }

  void Update () {
    movePlayer();
    detectMovementDirection();
  }

  private void detectMovementDirection() {
    if(isMovingVertical()) {
      moveVertical();
    } else {
      moveHorizontal();
    }
  }

  private void moveHorizontal(){
    _playerAnimator.SetInteger("yMove", 0);
    if (isMovingRight()) {
      _playerAnimator.SetBool("xMove", true);
      _playerSpriteRenderer.flipX = false;
    } else if (isMovingLeft()) {
      _playerAnimator.SetBool("xMove", true);
      _playerSpriteRenderer.flipX = true;
    } else {
      _playerAnimator.SetBool("xMove", false);
    }
  }

  private void moveVertical(){
    _playerAnimator.SetBool("xMove", false);
    _playerSpriteRenderer.flipX = false;
    if(isMovingUp()) {
      _playerAnimator.SetInteger("yMove", 1);
    } else if (isMovingDown()) {
      _playerAnimator.SetInteger("yMove", -1);
    }
  }

  private bool isMovingVertical() {
    return movePlayerVertical != 0;
  }

  private bool isMovingUp() {
    return movePlayerVertical > 0;
  }

  private bool isMovingDown() {
    return movePlayerVertical < 0;
  }

  private bool isMovingRight() {
    return movePlayerHorizontal > 0;
  }

  private bool isMovingLeft() {
    return movePlayerHorizontal < 0;
  }

  private void movePlayer(){
    movePlayerHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    movePlayerVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    movement = new Vector2(movePlayerHorizontal, movePlayerVertical);
    _playerRigidbody2D.velocity = movement * speed;
  }
}
```

The code is exactly the same, but I broke it up in smaller methods(a la Ruby) and the `#Update` method, now consists of only 2 calls which in my opinion, makes the code easier to reason about.

Is there an experienced C# programmer that can enlighten me if 1 of the coding style is better and if so why?

Comment: You can't learn a good C# style with Unity, it breaks so many rules  that it's almost an anti-pattern.

Comment: Where in your "refactoring" is the `moving` property updated?

Comment: @RolandIllig you are correct, it's not implemented yet. I will update the question ASAP. But please tell me your opinion on splitting up the method into multiple smaller methods.

Comment: I would not extract the single-line expressions into their own methods. The others are fine with me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing that catches my eye is that you are determining if you are moving in direction by testing your variable value against **0**. You shouldn't use 0 for that as short movements combined with some velocity calculations can make it seems like you are moving when you are not. Instead test it against **0.1**.

There are few problems with your 2 main methods - `movePlayer` && `detectMovementDirection`.

- You need to call 2 different methods in order for your character movement and animation to play. This is weird because you can call `movePlayer` without invoking the later which will result in movement without animation. You're on the right track, they do 2 different things and that's why they should be in 2 different methods, but they are chained together. You cant just play movement animations without moving the actual character and vice-versa. I would suggest to call `detectMovementDirection` at the end of your `movePlayer` method like this:

  ```
  private void movePlayer()
  {
      movePlayerHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
      movePlayerVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
      movement = new Vector2(movePlayerHorizontal, movePlayerVertical);
      _playerRigidbody2D.velocity = movement * speed;
      detectMovementDirection();
  }
  ```
- `detectMovementDirection` should be called something like `PlayMovementAnimation`.

Speaking of `detectMovementDirection`, you shouldn't have all those 1 liners and in fact you don't need to know exactly where your character is moving.

Let's start by simplifying your `moveVertical` method.

Take a look at this if statement:

> ```
> if (isMovingUp())
> {
>     _playerAnimator.SetInteger("yMove", 1);
> }
> else if (isMovingDown())
> {
>     _playerAnimator.SetInteger("yMove", -1);
> }
> ```

We can see that there is just a small difference between the 2 bodies and that's just the number 1 and -1. Let's extract some information:

> We know that that the range of `movePlayerVertical` is [-1, 1].
>
> `if (isMovingUp())` will be triggered only when `movePlayerVertical > 0`.
>
> `else if (isMovingDown())` will be triggered only when `movePlayerVertical < 0`.

With that information we can see that we move up when `movePlayerVertical` is positive and move down when it's negative. Well that's pretty good news because they are matching with what value we give to `_playerAnimator.SetInteger("yMove", x);`.

Well what if we round up the value of `movePlayerVertical` always to the nearest integer like this?

```
_playerAnimator.SetInteger("yMove", Mathf.RoundToInt(movePlayerVertical));
```

With this line we can remove 2 of your methods reduce the size of your `moveVertical` method.

```
private void moveVertical()
{
    _playerAnimator.SetBool("xMove", false);
    _playerSpriteRenderer.flipX = false;
    _playerAnimator.SetInteger("yMove", Mathf.RoundToInt(movePlayerVertical));
}
```

Let's inspect the `moveHorizontal()` method.

> ```
> private void moveHorizontal()
> {
>     _playerAnimator.SetInteger("yMove", 0);
>     if (isMovingRight())
>     {
>         _playerAnimator.SetBool("xMove", true);
>         _playerSpriteRenderer.flipX = false;
>     }
>     else if (isMovingLeft())
>     {
>         _playerAnimator.SetBool("xMove", true);
>         _playerSpriteRenderer.flipX = true;
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         _playerAnimator.SetBool("xMove", false);
>     }
> }
> ```

Take a look at the `else` statement here. When will this be triggered? Only when the previous 2 statements are wrong, let's put in a different way:

**It will always happen unless there is something to negate it.**

This means we can do this:

```
_playerAnimator.SetBool("xMove", false);
if (isMovingRight())
{
    _playerAnimator.SetBool("xMove", true);
    _playerSpriteRenderer.flipX = false;
}
else if (isMovingLeft())
{
    _playerAnimator.SetBool("xMove", true);
    _playerSpriteRenderer.flipX = true;
}
```

But we can shorten that even further, `xMove` has value true only if one of the 2 statements is correct, in all the rest cases it's false. We can do this:

```
_playerAnimator.SetBool("xMove", isMovingRight() || isMovingLeft());
```

Which makes our if statements seems pretty empty as they have only 1 line - `_playerSpriteRenderer.flipX = ???;`. Can we shorten this? Of course!

`_playerSpriteRenderer.flipX = isMovingLeft();`

This reduces your method to just 3 lines:

```
private void moveHorizontal()
{
    _playerAnimator.SetInteger("yMove", 0);
    _playerAnimator.SetBool("xMove", isMovingRight() || isMovingLeft());
    _playerSpriteRenderer.flipX = isMovingLeft();
}
```

Next we can simplify your `Awake` method.

> ```
> void Awake()
> {
>     _playerRigidbody2D = (Rigidbody2D) GetComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D));
>     _playerAnimator = (Animator) GetComponent(typeof(Animator));
>     _playerSpriteRenderer = (SpriteRenderer) GetComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer));
> }
> ```

There are 2 problems here:

1. It's ugly.
2. It involves *unboxing*.

We can fix those 2 problems easily using *generics*:

```
void Awake()
{
    _playerRigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    _playerAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    _playerSpriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}
```

You're not really following the C# naming conventions but I will leave that for someone else to comment on.

Comment: this is exactly the kind of advice I was looking for! Thank you Denis!
About the _unboxing_ inside the Awake method,
it's the suggested method by the author of the book *Mastering Unity 2D Game Development - Second Edition*.
Apparently there is a slight gain in performance by doing it this way. But using the generics looks cleaner, I agree.
About the naming conventions, you are correct, I must do some research.
I learned a lot from your answer! That was a really good breakdown!